# reRendering is not happening in jsf using data table

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Rerendering is not working in my code:

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel id="bookIncomeHeader1" value="#{myBean.ftBoookIncomelst}"
    label="BOOK INCOME" bodyClass="STP" style="ReptxtBold Reptxt_LtPad"
    switchType="server">
    <rich:dataTable id="bookIncome" value="#{myBean.ftBoookIncomelst}" var="item"
        rowKeyVar="row" first="0" width="100%">
        <rich:subTable id="subBookIncome"value="#{item.txIncome}" var="income"
            rowKeyVar="row">
            <rich:column id="descrtiptionColumn" width="30%">
                <h:outputText value="#{income.descriptionCell.value}"
                     rendered="#{!item.editableRow}" 
                     style="#{income.descriptionCell.boldClass}" />  
                <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" required="true" 
                     value="#{income.descriptionCell.value}" 
                     rendered="#{item.editableRow}" 
                     requiredMessage="Description at row #{row+1} wasn't filled."
                     changedHoverClass="hover" viewHoverClass="hover" 
                     viewClass="inplace" changedClass="inplace" 
                     selectOnEdit="true" editEvent="onclick" />
            </rich:column>
```

In the above code I have proper `id` for datatable and I'm calling my ajax call using:

```
<rich:menuItem value="Add Manual Adjustment" id="addmanualadjust">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{myBean.addNewDataItem}" 
        reRender="bookIncome">
        <f:param name="rowNum" value="#{item.serialNum}"></f:param>
    </a4j:support>
</rich:menuItem>
```

It's hitting the server and calling proper method and updating the required list, but it's not showing any response. Why is it not rendering? It does not show any exception on console either.

Comment: how did you manage to resolve this issue BalusC? I am stuck on the same exact problem.

Comment: @Srinivas, Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 1):

1. the `a4j:support` and the `dataTable` should be in the same `<x:form>`
2. try adding `immediate="true"` to the `a4j:support` to bypass validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you rerender bookIncomeHeader1?

Max
http://mkblog.exadel.com